# How can I send a forgot password email from outside Visual Force Page?

Tags: apex, community, rest-api

We have implemented a forgot password visual force page which is working when we access it through the browser. We also create a custom REST service which is using the same Site.ForgotPassword(username); apex code.

Problem is that when we GET the rest service the email to reset the password is not sent.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm#apex_System_Site_forgotPassword) outside of a visual force page the method should always return false. I noticed it always returns false but does that also mean that outside of a visual force page you can not do forgotpassword?

Thanks